# Rails showing all data from database to index page how to stop it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new in rails and i have generated a resource named a company name:string bio:text and ceo:string but my index view showing all the db records but i haven't done any inspet so why it showing all the data in index page?

it showing like this

[#<Company id: 4, name: "google", bio: "ad company", ceo: "sundar pichaif", created_at: "2021-03-15 12:43:18.821528000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-03-15 13:05:49.407986000 +0000">, #<Company id: 5, name: "basecamp", bio: "task management", ceo: "jason fried", created_at: "2021-03-15 13:27:58.781628000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-03-15 13:27:58.781628000 +0000">, #<Company id: 6, name: "Github", bio: "code", ceo: "Chris Wanstrath", created_at: "2021-03-15 13:30:15.510656000 +0000", updated_at: "2021-03-15 13:30:55.654182000 +0000">]

please help me out :(

Comment: update the question with controller index method as well

Comment: you should post your controller and view code. But probably you've got somewhere `@companies = Company.all`, and in your view you just display it `<%= @companies %>`. You should read about https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_view_overview.html#erb

Comment: What @nuaky said or you have `<%= @companies.each do |company| %>`. In either case just remove the `=` and you won't see the output of the `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

open your index file where it shows the data from your database, please remove  "=" for example: remove this <%= @companies %> and add like this <% @companies %>, the reason I am telling you to remove is that when you use "=" this sign with <%= ..... %>, it will show all the data in this erb brackets, so remove this and your issue will be resolve, Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help